# How could I be getting an expected str instance, NoneType found error when I'm using a default get in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I see this error:

```
data["source_domain"], data["ip_address"]])
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

But this is my code leading up to that error:

```
    data["segment_user_id"] = record.get("userId", "")
    traits = record.get("traits", {})
    data.update({
        # country_name -> country
        trait.replace("country_name", "country"): traits.get(trait, "")
        for trait in ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "country_name", "city", "ip_address"]
    })

    # Add composite key
    to_hash = ''.join([data["project_id"], data["anonymous_id"], data["source_system"], data["segment_user_id"],
                       data["source_domain"], data["ip_address"]])
    data["message_composite_key"] = hashlib.md5(to_hash.encode()).hexdigest()
```

It seems like the sequence number 3 which is `data["segment_user_id"]` is None. But how could this be? Isn't my `record.get("userId", "")` code ensuring that this always gets set to empty string?